# How to do a set -u locally in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I would like to turn on

```
set -u
```

only inside the body of one zsh function. At the end of the function, it should be restored to its previous state.

I reckon that I have to do a

```
setopt localoptions ????
```

inside the function, but what comes at the place of the ???? ? From the zsh manpage, I found an explanation for the option `UNSET`, but this corresponds to `set +u`, not `set -u`.

**UPDATE**:

Based on the answer given by chepner, I also tried:

```
set -u
foo() {
 setopt NO_UNSET LOCAL_OPTIONS
 echo $xx
}
bar() {
 setopt localoptions nounset
 echo $xx
}
```

But both functions, when invoked, abort with *xx: parameter not set*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set -u` is equivalent to `setopt no_unset` and `set +u` is equivalent to `setopt unset`. You've inverted the meaning.

```
set -u
foo() {
 setopt local_options unset
 echo $xx
}
foo # prints an empty line
echo $xx # errors out
```

Documentation references:

- Long option documentation: [`UNSET`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-UNSET) is equivalent to `+u` (not to `-u`)
- [Single letter option documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Single-Letter-Options): `-u` is equivalent to `NO_UNSET` (not to `UNSET`)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of the `UNSET` option is `NO_UNSET`

```
foo () {
    setopt NO_UNSET LOCAL_OPTIONS
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your variant, and I also tried `setopt localoptions nounset`, but still no effect. Please look at my updated question, where I included your suggestion, with the exact code that I tried.